# is it possible update ui from fragment from another fragment onclick in android

Tags: android

I am adding two fragment in one activity .I am setting onclick listener in fragment button view.In fragment click listener how to update the another fragment view in android

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to contact the activity first which will contact the second fragment. and also read this article on how to do it...

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html#CommunicatingWithActivity